# Create associative array with value as key

Tags: php

I have this array with information, which I want to create a new associative array with. Each key in the associative array should be the "name" from the old one. And in each new key, I want the corresponding information to be collected.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [counter] => 21478813
            [serie] => 2607171234
            [name] => Ben
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [counter] => 21478858
            [serie] => 2607177151
            [name] => Evan
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [counter] => 21478817
            [serie] => 2607171341
            [name] => Steve
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [counter] => 21471798
            [serie] => 2607178561
            [name] => Ben
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [counter] => 21478811
            [serie] => 2607171347
            [name] => Ben
        )
)
```

This is the array I'm trying to create:

```
Array
(
    ["Ben"] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [counter] => 21478813
                    [serie] => 2607171234
                    [name] => Ben
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [counter] => 21471798
                    [serie] => 2607178561
                    [name] => Ben
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [counter] => 21478811
                    [serie] => 2607171347
                    [name] => Ben
                )
        )
    ["Evan"] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [counter] => 21478858
                    [serie] => 2607177151
                    [name] => Evan
                )
        )
    ["Steve"] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [counter] => 21478817
                    [serie] => 2607171341
                    [name] => Steve
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: show us how are you trying ?

Comment: Please post what you have tried to do to solve the issue, and what trouble you've had with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newArr = array();

foreach($myArr as $value) {
    $name = $value['name'];
    if (isset($newArr[$name])) {
        $newArr[$name][] = $value;
    }
    else {
        $newArr[$name] = array($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks alot for your help! And i'll make sure I submit my attempted code next time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` loop to create a new array:

```
$newArr = [];

foreach($myArr as $key => $value){
    $newArr[$myArr[$key][$value['name']]][] = $myArr[$key];
}
```

Comment: You can simplify the line inside the `foreach` like this: `$newArr[$myArr[$i]['name']][] = $v;`

Comment: Your solution produced several E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined index: messages when I tried it.

Comment: @DavidAman You didn't use my code then, I'm not calling index messages.

Comment: @Daan, I tried your code in PHP fiddle. That message refers to accessing an array item that doesn't exist.

Comment: @DavidAman I know what the message means. But like I said I'm not calling the index messages.